# Find if substring exists in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, substr

I have a lot of strings, and I need to check if each of them contains a color.

For example :

- A bird in the sky
- 22 street of France
- The dog is blue
- The cat is black and white

So, the two last strings must return true.

What is the best way to find it?

Regex, or check with any substr() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In regexp you can write

```
preg_match_all("/(red|blue|black|white|etc)/", $haystack, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Use a loop for all the strings, and you'll easily notice which of the values from $matches you need.

Answer (score 27):

I always work with `strpos` since it seems to be the fastest alternative (don't know about regex though).

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE) return $haystack;
```

Comment: I've find a function wich use strpos, with an array of $needles

Comment: strpos does not return TRUE, but it does return FALSE so you can do `if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE) return $haystack;` and another thing to remember is if you were looking for `red` then `fred` would also return a result.

Comment: @pathfinder You're absolutely right, seems like I was not paying attention :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is faster than regex. Also beware that if [`strpos`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is case sensitive. If you need to search the substring regardless of case you should use [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Answer (score 3):

if you will use strpos then it returns a position of a string it will return a number 1,2,3 etc not true or false.

And the other problem is if string exist at the start it will return 0 which will consider as false then strpos cannot find that word.

Comment: Just use === operator

Answer (score 1):

strpos or strripos in php should be able to search for a single word in a string.
You may have to loop in order to search for all colors if using it though

Comment: also saw an example somewhere about eregi
eregi("(this|that)", $str) //finds this or that in $str